# Why std::set does not provide try_emplace member function?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, unordered-set, emplace

One advantage of `try_emplace` member function of `std::map` (and `std::unordered_map`) is that it does not allocate a new node if the key already exists in the map. I wonder why this member function has not been added to the `std::set` (and `std::unordered_set`) interface, where the same advantage might apply as well.

This live demo shows that `std::set::emplace` allocates each time: https://godbolt.org/z/MjMjPcc89 (with libstdc++).

And this benchmark shows that `find` + `emplace` may be faster than `emplace` alone when there are duplicated keys: https://quick-bench.com/q/2IWzv_SJFJpklGjwIKk6wgKsuz0.

However, `find` + `emplace` requires a double lookup in case the key is not present in the container. Here is the benchmark for `std::map`, where `try_emplace` is the fastest option: https://quick-bench.com/q/ymn1qaxAtrf6FTzHC98e_wkHVZ4.

**EDIT**

It seems the problem with allocations does not occur when `std::set::insert` is used. My bad I haven't tried it before.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/EjWjfjnsc

Comment: you need a `Key` for `try_emplace`. Sets don't have keys, but you need to construct the whole element to be able to compare it to others.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sets don't have keys? Quoting from the standard: _"A set is an associative container that supports unique keys (contains at most one of each key value) and provides for fast retrieval of the keys themselves."_ (http://eel.is/c++draft/set#overview-1.sentence-1)

Comment: well ok they are called Keys, but thats already the element. In maps you have Keys and the mapped value, and you only need the Key to see if inserting needs to take place. Anyhow, I am not sure if this is a good argument, in particular I am not sure if it is possible to use an overloaded comparator that would allow to compare some `T` to the keys

Comment: The difference is, that if you add a value to a set, which already exists in the set, the set remains unchanged (no duplicates etc.). So, the adding to a set always succeeds, independent of whether the item is in the set already or not.

Comment: @BitTickler why is that a difference? If you try to insert into a map where the Key is already present then the map is not modified as well

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `try_emplace` for `set` could require a key as an argument. The same holds for `std::map::try_emplace`.

Comment: @DanielLangr - So you want to save on constructing the value type (which is the key), by adding the constructed key?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I want to save on allocations.

Comment: If it "could require a key as an argument", then, @DanielLangr, how would that differ from `insert()`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It won't. But insert always allocates a node.

Comment: @DanielLangr - That's what plain emplace does already. Construct the key, but don't allocate internal data until insertion is needed.

Comment: This sounds like a defective implementation of `insert()`. Nothing in the standard requires that.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Please, see the godbolt link. There, inserting allocates 10 times when the same key is 10 times used. But I just checked it does not happen with `insert`, only with `emplace`: https://godbolt.org/z/EjWjfjnsc. It seems you're right.

Comment: @DanielLangr - I've seen the link, a sub-optimal implementation doesn't negate the leeway given by the specification.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It seems that with `insert`, the allocation does not happen with the same key. My bad I haven't tried it before.

Comment: You could use `lower_bound` (maybe `upper_bound`, some experimentation is needed to see which one works better) followed by `emplace_hint`, if needed, to avoid most of the cost of a 2nd lookup, in order to work around this implementation. This is most likely a gamble that most use cases of std::set do not attempt to insert a large number of duplicate keys, so its optimized for the most common use case.

Comment: i remember to have read some guide that suggested to use `emplace` rather than `insert` because it can do the same. This seems to be a counter example. Though I suppose nothing in the standard would forbid to have a specialization for emplace that does not allocate when not required

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number In case of sets, you cannot change the value (the key is the value), in contrast to a map, where you can overwrite the value under the same key: `std::map<uint32_t,uint32_t> m; m[0] = 0; m[0] = 1;` This is a non-issue with sets.

Comment: @BitTickler but both `insert` and `emplace` are about inserting a new element, not about modifying an existing one.

Comment: Insert is actually an "update" if the key already exists in a map. And it potentially changes the maps content, whereas with sets, this is not the case.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, this is a counter-example. I maybe won't delete the question for this reason. Anyway, `emplace` needs to construct the key and if it won't happen in the allocated node directly, it would also then need to copy or move the key in case of insertion. Which I don't know if it's allowed. But yes, there may be specializations allowed for `emplace` if the key type is the type of the argument. That's a good question.

Comment: @BitTickler Insert with `insert` or `emplace` does not change the map if the key already exists in it. `operator[]` is a different case, which it's off-topic to this question.

Comment: @BitTickler thats not correct. `insert` does not modify an element when an element with equivalent key is already present https://godbolt.org/z/Er648xbTn

Comment: You are right! C++17 mixed it up some. The function I had in mind goes by `insert_or_assign()`. They could as well have just called it "upsert()" as that name is well known e.g. in the database world. My prime c++ times were before C++11 and so I do not keep up well with that moving target ;)

Answer (score 0):

[std::set::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace) and [std::unordered_set::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/emplace) are already equivalent to `try_emplace`:

> Inserts a new element into the container constructed in-place with the given args if there is no element with the key in the container.

However, be aware that:

> The element may be constructed even if there already is an element with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately.